# JavaScriptCore crash on UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsattributedstring

I am getting the following crash in my application. I am using `UIWebviews` and `NSAttributedString`. I do not know where this crash comes from.

> ## 0 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000bbadbeef  Raw 0
>
> 0 JavaScriptCore   bmalloc::VMHeap::grow() + 132 1 JavaScriptCore
> bmalloc::VMHeap::grow() + 56   45 UIKit    UIApplicationMain + 204 46
> Notebook   main.m line 29 main     47 libdyld.dylib    start + 4

Can somebody help me out on this?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your crash log give you lot of information.

```
0 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000bbadbeef Raw 0
```

This means you tried to access to address 0 into ur program and kernel is not happy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=146598.

Specifically, it's trying to grow the heap for its custom allocator, and exploding instead. I see this in another app when it's incredibly low on memory. This occurs in a thread devoted to WebKit—no app functions appear in the crashed thread's call stack.